# Change the value of an evaluated var in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a var containing a JSON string. (Here I won't parse it because it is not the main problem)

```
var variable = '{"name":"Johnny Appleseed"}';
var string = "variable";
```

I evaluate the string.

```
var evaluatedstring = eval(string);
```

Now I would like to delete the value of the var variable.

```
variable = undefined;
```

If I do:

```
console.log(evaluatedstring)
```

It works fine and returns me the JSON string as:

```
{"name":"Johnny Appleseed"}
```

But if I do:

```
evaluatedstring = undefined;
```

Of course it doesn't work.

```
eval(string) = undefined;
```

doesn't work either. (Returns the error Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment)

How can I delete the content that via the evaluated var?

- No jQuery, please.
- On Chrome 50+ so not a problem with the browser.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? "Deleting" a variable is weird.

Comment: More like removing the content of the var actually

Comment: If you want to clear a variable, you can just make it an empty string. var x = "";, that is. Also, it thinks you're trying to check whether eval(string) evaluates to false.

Comment: The thing is that I am trying to do that with dynamically changing variable names

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? What is the result you're expecting? @orlandomarinella I think that's not entirely correct, it thinks you're trying to ASSIGN a value to a function expression. Also to "unset" it should be x = undefined instead of the empty string.

Comment: I would like var variable to be empty

Comment: @BadIdeaException Good point. x = undefined makes x empty.

Are you trying to create an _alias_ for var variable? Because, again, I'm not quite sure what's going on here. (javascript doesn't like aliasing.)

Comment: Then do variable = undefined as suggested by @orlandomarinella and me. Note though that this won't change the value of either string or evaluatedString.

Comment: Please take a look at the question. I already know how to do that. I need to do that with a many changing variable name. Say _another_ var variable_2. I could have as many as I want, but I need to change it based on interactions with the webpage.

Comment: Variable names don't really just change. You can create new variables, but the old ones don't really go away. So, you can pass the value of var x to var y, then clear var x, but var y won't clear just because var x is. What you can do, though, is create an object. So, `var x = 1, var y = function { return x };`, so when you do `x++`, console.log(y) will return '2'.

Comment: Am I understand you correctly that you're trying to set a variable to undefined where the name of the variable is only known in a string?

Comment: What you're trying to do is an unnatural thing in JavaScript. Things get *much* easier if you work with object properties instead of variables. Then you can simply use `[ ]` references to use dynamic names as object property references.

Comment: Of course I understand your points, this is really quite confusing as the object being interacted with is dependent on the user. So is it really quite impossible for this to be done? @BadIdeaException Yep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're working in the browser: Global variables in JavaScript are created as properties of the `window` object. Therefore, what you're trying to do can be done like this:

```
var variable = 'some variable';
var variableName = 'variable';

window[variableName] = undefined;

variable === undefined // Will now be true
```

However, just the fact that this is possible doesn't mean it's a good idea - in fact, it's just the opposite, it's bad style and will probably confuse anyone looking at your program to no end. If this is really necessary for your algorithm to work, you might want to rethink your data architecture. If this is just a scoping issue (you don't want that variable to pollute your global namespace), an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) will likely solve your problem.

Comment: So I understand that if I may be doing this again I should use a dictionary instead?

Comment: I can't really answer that properly, because I still can't imagine why you would want to do this. Are you sure there isn't a better way?